# Joining two tables to get the exact date

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I Have two tables,

1st table --> loan ,
columns --> pos_num , pos_type

2nd table --> payment,
columns --> pos_num , pos_type , date

I want to extract pos_num , pos_type values from loan and place in the below query

`select count(1) from payment where pos_num = <value extracted from loans> and pos_type = <value extracted from loans> and date = <?>`

How can we i join loan table with payment table to get the date where we should have same data in payment table for pos_num , pos_type that we got from loan table

Comment: Would it be fair to say your actual question is, *"what is the syntax to join LOAN table with PAYMENT table?"*

Comment: @APC , yes and i want the date from payment table , where  pos_num , pos_type of both the table should be same

Comment: You want to get the date(s) from the payment table; or find a payment made on a specific date? And are there other column in `loan` that you're using to decide which `pos_num`/`pos_type` values to look for? If not why are you involving the `loan` table at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values with JOIN sentence like:

```
SELECT pos_num , pos_type , date
FROM loans L
JOIN payment P ON L.pos_num = P.pos_num AND L.pos_type = P.pos_type;
```

I hope to be helpful.

Comment: The projection includes columns from both tables which have the same name. So we need to give them a table alias to avoid `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` exception.

Comment: Can we write in this way,

Comment: SELECT pos_num , pos_type , date
FROM loans L,  payment P where L.pos_num = P.pos_num AND L.pos_type = P.pos_type;  @Camila Alvarado